# Scroll left and right horizontal div

Tags: jquery, css

I'm using `jquery.mousewheel.js` to scroll my div and I'm using this code:

```
#scrollableDiv {
    //position: relative;
    width: auto;
    height: 550px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    padding: 5px;
    background-image: url(<?= base_url(); ?>/uploads/rcrayon_background-blue_preview.png);
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

#scrollableDiv img {
    padding: 5px;
}
```

How can I add left and right buttons to scroll inside the div?

Comment: I gues that there is a function in `jquery.mousewheel.js` that can scroll a div horizontal. Just detect a left an right click button and than assign the right scroll function to it

Comment: @Vinc199789 thanks, I'll look for it.

Comment: I tried copying the initialization code of the mousewheel.js: '$('#scrollableDiv').mousewheel(function(e, delta) {
                this.scrollLeft -= (delta * 40);
                e.preventDefault();
                });'  to a click function but it didn't work. I also try '$('#scrollableDiv').animate({
                  marginLeft: "-=200px"
                }, "fast");' and it's not working also. Is there any other way to scroll a div horizontally?. Thanks.

Comment: If you can detect if the visitor is scrolling up or down than you can add `$('#scrollableDiv').animate({ marginLeft: "-=200px" }, "fast");` but I never used a scroll plugin so I am trying to fix this without a plugin

Comment: Thanks. I'm trying to imitate the scrolling in [nickjr.com](http://nickjr.com), any suggestions?